# Winforms Core .NET 5. add a Sub Menu To A ContextMenuStrip

Tags: winforms

I am trying to create a sub menu or cascading menu on the ContextMenuStrip in WinForm core.

```
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Clear();
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("UPPER MENU"));
MenuStrip submenu = new MenuStrip();
submenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("SUB MENU1"));
submenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("SUB MENU2"));
```

How do I add the sub menu to "UPPER MENU1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items have to be added to the `DropDown` of the `UPPER MENU` item, e.g:

```
var upperMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("UPPER MENU");
upperMenu.DropDown.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("SUB MENU1"));
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(upperMenu);
```